# returning value from a function using the async module node

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am attempting to write a function that uses the async module's parallel function and returns a value to the calling function like so...

```
_refillActivePool() {
    let _this = this;
    let currentCnt;

    async.parallel([
            function (callback) {
                Participants.count()
                .then(count => {
                    currentCnt = count;
                    callback();
                });
            },
            function (callback) {
                Participants.fetchAll()
                .then(results => {
                    let participants = [];
                    results.forEach(result => {
                        participants.push(result.get('full_name'));
                    });
                    _this._addToActivePool(participants);
                    callback();
                });
            }
        ],
        function (err) {
            if (err) {
                throw err;
            }
            return currentCnt;
        }
    );
}
```

calling function looks like this

```
pick() {
    return ActivePool.count()
    .then(count => {
        if (!count) {
            console.log(`new count: ${this._refillActivePool()}`);
        }
    });
}
```

when I log the return value in the calling function, I get a value of undefined. Can someone please give me some direction on how to accomplish this or a better way of achieving my goal. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Async.js don't return promises. Instead all functions in async accept callbacks. If you want to use promises check out async-q instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your function to return a promise (which is needed to use `.then()` on it) you would have to do something like this:

```
_refillActivePool() {
    return new Promise(resolve, reject) {
        let _this = this;
        let currentCnt;

        async.parallel([
                function (callback) {
                    Participants.count()
                    .then(count => {
                        currentCnt = count;
                        callback();
                    });
                },
                function (callback) {
                    Participants.fetchAll()
                    .then(results => {
                        let participants = [];
                        results.forEach(result => {
                            participants.push(result.get('full_name'));
                        });
                        _this._addToActivePool(participants);
                        callback();
                    });
                }
            ],
            function (err) {
                if (err) {
                    return reject(err);
                }
                resolve(currentCnt);
            }
        );
    });
}
```

and then run it as:

```
_refillActivePool().then(value => {
  // use the value here
}).catch(error => {
  // handle error here
});
```

Note: this is not tested. It may still have some issues other than the ones I fixed.